# Import Headerless CSV into Data Grid View using first row as header

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, datasource

I have the following code which pulls the data from a CSV file specified by the user. The CSV file is without any headers and has four columns of data. I'm trying to import this data into the dataGridView datasource, but get unexpected results. Each time, it takes the first row and makes it the header column. I tried inserting a row at the beginning (commented out text), but it will only add the row to the datasource, but not treat it as the header. I'm not too worried about having headers, but would like my data to not "omit" the first row since it sees it as a header.

```
string sql_select;
string strConnString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(odfDeficit.FileName).Trim() + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(strConnString.Trim());
sql_select = "select * from [" + Path.GetFileName(odfDeficit.FileName).Trim() + "]";
OdbcDataAdapter obj_oledb_da = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql_select, conn);
obj_oledb_da.Fill(ds, "csv");

//DataRow dr;
//dr = ds.Tables["csv"].NewRow();
//dr[0] = "First Name";
//dr[1] = "Last Name";
//dr[2] = "Last Four of SSN";
//dr[3] = "Deficit Amount";
//ds.Tables["csv"].Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["csv"];
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly creating the columns for the table, and then loading the table with the CSV file?

```
DataTable csvTable = new DataTable();

csvTable.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(String));
csvTable.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(String));
csvTable.Columns.Add("LastFourOfSSN", typeof(String));
csvTable.Columns.Add("DeficitAmount", typeof(String));

obj_oledb_da.Fill(csvTable);

dataGridView1.DataSource = csvTable;
```

I can't say for certain this will work, but it's worth a try.

Also, out of curiosity, why are using Odbc?  You could use OleDb or even the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` class.  I'm not saying Odbc is wrong, just presenting a couple of alternative ways.

Comment: when I tried `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;` it gave an error saying that it couldn't be found. I have never used Visual C# before, but was given the task to learn it in a day and create an ETL tool. Sucks for me. However, I've told them that they need to include header rows in the CSV that they're giving me. That is the only way that it will work. I do like your method the best. not sure if it will work, but seems legit enough.

Answer (score 0):

Insert record by using column names

```
DataRow dr = ds.Tables["csv"].NewRow();
dr.ItemArray = ds.Tables["csv"].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToArray();
ds.Tables["csv"].Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);
```

Or you can try [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)